# Regular expression to check only alphabets

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms, validation

**I am trying to achieve form validation of only alphabets but this regular expression doesnt seem to work**

```
 function check() {
      var reg="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/";
    var x = document.forms['frm'].name.value;
    var y=  document.forms['frm'].email.value;

    if( x === ""){
     alert('Name field cant be empty');
     $("#nameone").focus();
      return false;
    }
    else if (!reg.match(x)){
      alert('NAME must contain alphabets only');
      return false;
    }

    else if( y === ""){
     alert('Email  field cant be empty');
     $("#emailone").focus();
      return false;
    }



    else {
      return true;
    }
    }
```

> this is my form ,i have added the details ,the input fields

```
 <form class="reg_form" name='frm' method="post" onsubmit='return check();' >
     <div class="input-field col-md-4">
      <input type="text" placeholder="1. Name" name="name" id='nameone'/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col-md-4">
      <input type="text" placeholder="2. Email" name="email" id='emailone'  />
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col-md-4 ">
     <input type="text" placeholder="3. phone" name="phone" />
     </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Try to use `reg.test()` instead of `reg.match()`

Comment: that doesnt seems to work for me !!

Comment: `var reg="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/";` this will create a string and not regex, you want to do `var reg= /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;` and then use `x.match(reg)`

Comment: Shouldn't you have some actual, like, *items* in your form? Or is that just a simplified version to show the attributes used?

Comment: obviously its an simplified version ,let me add the details

Comment: You've used `.match()` wrongly. It should be `x.match(reg)`. It is defined at `String.prototype.match`

Comment: As a side note, you can incorporate your "is the string empty" condition in your regex by using the "at-least-one" `+` quantifier instead of the "any-number" `*`

Comment: George was right ,i was making it a string !! now its working fine ! thanks

Answer (score 2):

In this case, your code isn't working 'cause your regex was set as a string in the line:

```js
 var reg="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/";
```

The regex was suposed to be set without quotes:

```js
 var reg=/^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
```

I suggest that instead of the method 'match', you use:

```js
else if (!reg.test(x)){
```

This is more performatic and return a boolean value.

Comment: I don't think "performatic" is a word ; did you mean "efficient" ?

Comment: I mean performatic indeed. The method test only check the string, match check, splits the string to return the matched value. You can check here a benchmark https://jsperf.com/exec-vs-match-vs-test-vs-search/2

Comment: I can't find "performatic" defined in any dictionary though ([here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=performatic&go=Look+up&searchToken=bd4dkh45n0588bf2pqtj1gzjb) is wiktionary failing to define it), and "[efficient](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/efficient)" (not to be confused with "effective") seems to match the advantage that your definition points out : not wasting resource doing useless or overly complicated things. Note that I'm not a native english speaker, so I might very well be confused. Or it could be a local idiom, which I guess should then be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of...

```
var reg = "/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"; // produces a **string**
```

You should omit the surrounding quotes:

```
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;  // produces a **Regex object**
```

The second uses javascript inline Regex syntax, with the slashes functioning as delimiters.

Furthermore you can use the simple `.test()` function to check if a string conforms to a Regex or not.

Demo:

```js
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
console.log(reg.test("ABcd"));
console.log(reg.test("123"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
string.match("^[a-zA-Z]+$$");
```

you will get true if the string contains only letters and false otherwise